# Why does my div does not recognize the height of custom components inside itself?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a div that has a handful of custom components in it, and I'm trying to put a border around that container, but the container div's height is not affected by it's contents.

This is a mock up of the div

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black">
    <myCustomComponent1></myCustomComponent1>
    <myCustomComponent2></myCustomComponent2>
    <myCustomComponent3></myCustomComponent3>
</div>
```

Where `myCustomComponent1`, `2`, and `3` point to different html files that contain varying contents that, for the sake of this example, would make each one be a height of `200px` and width of `400px`.

So I would expect the div containing these to have a border that is 400px wide, and 600px tall. But instead the border appears only as a narrow box at the top of my elements.

Comment: Without knowing the CSS, and HTML of the contained components it's impossible to say.

Comment: Custom elements don't have display set by default, try setting it to block or something, but as Don says, without more info can't say. ;)

Comment: Does css include display:block; property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is that the contained components are floating, thus taken out of the flow of the document. In order to get the container to resize to fit floating children make the container a block formatting context by adding `overflow: hidden` to the style of the container.

Another option is to set the `display` on the contained elements to `display: block` or `display: inline-block` depending on how they should act. This is needed because of the custom tag name.

*If this turns out to not be the issue I'll update this answer, but as of now it's hard to say as not enough information is given*

Comment: Inline block fixed my problem! I'm not the best when it comes to the css stuff, definitely still learning all the ins and outs of the tools I have available to me when messing with styles. Applying an, inline-block to the container and it's contents gave me the exact behaviour I was expecting. Thanks so much for the help!